# Replace multiple \r\n occurrences in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Let imagine this string:

> hey \r\n\r\n I am a robot \r\n I am a dog \r\n\r\n

how can I using Java replace it to

> "hey \r\n I am a robot \r\n I am a dog \r\n" ?

Only one occurrence of

> \r\n ?

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("(\r\n){2,}", "\r\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace:

```
String s = "hey \r\n\r\n I am a robot \r\n I am a dog \r\n\r\n";
System.out.println("Original: " + s);
s = s.replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
System.out.println("Result: " + s);
```

will print:

```
Original: hey 

 I am a robot 
 I am a dog 


Result: hey 
 I am a robot 
 I am a dog
```

and if there is a case of more than 2 adjacent occurrences of `"\r\n"`:

```
while (s.contains("\r\n\r\n")) {
    s = s.replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do the job.

```
String messy_string = "hey \r\n\r\n I am a robot \r\n I am a dog \r\n\r\n";
String regex_pattern = "[\r\n]+";
String replacement = "\r\n";

String sanitized_str = messy_string.replaceAll(regex_pattern, replacement);
```